# A $2.0$ ton truck provides an acceleration of $3.0$ ft/s^2 to a $5.0$ ton trailer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

I am doing this problem for practice, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

> A $2.0$-ton truck provides an acceleration of $3.0 \frac{ft}{s^2}$ to
> a $5.0$-ton trailer. If the truck exerts the same force on the road
> while pulling a $15.0$-ton trailer, what acceleration results?

My logic is that because the $5.0$-ton trailer gets an acceleration of $3.0\frac{ft}{s^2}$, the total force that the truck applies on the trailer is $F=ma=15ton\frac{ft}{s^2}$. When the car is pulling the $15$-ton trailer with the same force, it's acceleration should be $a=\frac{F}{m}=\frac{15ton\frac{ft}{s^2}}{15 ton}=1\frac{ft}{s^2}$.

However, the correct answer should be $1.24\frac{ft}{s^2}$. Should I include the mass of the truck ? If yes , then why ?

Which step did I do wrong?

Comment: can you add a picture of this situation ?

Comment: @Ankit I'm sorry, but no picture was provided in the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , the truck too moves with the same acceleration as that of the $5\;ton$ trailer and both are moving because  the truck pushes the ground back and (from Newton's third law) the ground pushes the truck forward. That's why you need to include the mass of the truck too.

So the total force on that system(truck + trailer) is different and even when a trailer of different mass is used, the truck does accelerate with that trailer too.

Hope it helps ☺️.